.NET solution build fails in Jenkins
I have a .NET application/solution with over one hundred projects. As a part of an activity, I changed the TargetFramework of these projects from 4.6.1 to 4.6.2 (don't ask...).
Now my application builds and works just fine locally, in both debug and release modes.
But once I pushed my code and built my branch in Jenkins, it starts to fail.
I get several warnings, like:

warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.X.SomeAssembly" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

I'm not well-versed in Jenkins and MSDN articles are less than helpful.
Does anyone know or has faced a similar issues before? Any help will be immense.
Also, my Jenkins build environment is driven from a JenkinsFile which I cannot share.

An error with a code prefixed with MSB is coming from MSBuild. For MSB3277, see the documentation at "MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of 'assembly' that could not be resolved".

@JonathanDodds I have mentioned in the question that I've gone through the MSDN write-up. It isn't of much help. And all this is happening in Jenkins which makes it doubly difficult to debug.

Looks like cached dependency issue, are you using some kind of third party package repository like 'nuget' or nexus repos. In that case you might want to clean these from your workspace before actually building the project.
Another thing you might want to check/add is a workspace clean up before and after your build.  If you are doing this via jenkins pipeline, and using permanent agents in conjunction, cached dependencies might be your issue.
For example, if you are using nuget as a package manager, you might want to try something like this in your pipe dsl before you build the project :


bat 'dotnet nuget locals all --clear'



